# How to create a windows scheduler job using asp.net mvc web app from cron expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cron, quartz.net, windows-task-scheduler

I have a question is there any way to create windows scheduler job using ASP.NET MVC web app from my cron expression (string). I have generated this cron expression using a jQuery plugin. After generating cron expression string I need to schedule a job which has to be executed an .exe file on server for given interval of time (cron expression), It can also be a recursive job or simple job.

For example here I generated a cron expression using jQuery plugin to execute an .exe on `Every day at 12:00 PM`

`0 12 * * *`

How to create scheduler job using ASP.NET MVC from the above cron expression?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a Windows Scheduler, you need to do a lot of COM-object-related-stuff. Lucky you are, there is nice and shiny a Quartz.net project. Take a look at [this](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)

Comment: to work with Quartz.net, do we need to install Quartz.net on my server box? or just Quartz.net dll reference in web app is enough.

Comment: you've got a lot of options here. You can install Nuget package to your application and start Quartz along side your app. Or you can start Quartz in a seperate application (windows service?) and work with them via .NET Remoting. Or you can deploy a whole cluster of standalone Quartz-apps with load-balance and fail-over capabilities.